# Reversing classes, making method that just calls address

Tags: c++, class, assembly, methods, reverse

So I'm writing an 'extension' to one program (game to be exact). It's more of a hack.
Anyway, I'm reversing some classes, like character, item etc. I want to make good methods.

So I have made something like this :

### character.hpp

```
class CHARACTER
{
public:

int hp;
int level;
//....



int GetLevel(void);
void SetLevel(int lv);

};
```

### character.cpp

```
#include "character.hpp"

int CHARACTER::GetLevel(void)
{
    return ((int(*)(CHARACTER*))0xADDR)(this);
}

void CHARACTER::SetLevel(int lv)
{
    ((void(*)(CHARACTER*,int))0xADDR)(this,lv);
}
```

### main.cpp

```
void hook1(CHARACTER* pc)
{
    pc->SetLevel(99);
}
```

The problem is, the code is executing like twice. You push arguments in hook1
then you push them again in CHARACTER::SetLevel (pseudo asm below):
//////////////

```
hook1:

    push 99
    call CHARACTER__SetLevel


CHARACTER__SetLevel:

    push arg
    call 0xADDR
```

So I've tried to just make a jump, since you already have all arguments on the stack and you can just jump to the function. The problem is, the 'asm' adds

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp

void CHARACTER::SetLevel(int lv)
{
    asm(".intel_syntax\n"
        "mov eax, 0xADDR\n"
        "jmp eax\n"
    );
}

at the beginning. So I have to execute this code at address + 3

(If I'm making hook in only asm, I do something like this)

void hook_asm(void)
{
    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
        ".whatever\n"
        );
}

void MAIN_HOOK(void)
{
    JmpPatch(0xADDR, &hook_asm+3); // Skip push ebp and mov ebp, esp
}
```

////////////////////

So, the only solution I see is making it like

```
void asm_SetLevel(void)
{
    asm(".intel_syntax noprefix\n"
        "mov eax, 0xADDR\n"
        "jmp eax\n"
        );
}
CHARACTER::SetLevel(int lv)
{
    ((void(*)(void))&asm_SetLevel+3)();
}
```

But that's not what I wanted to do, besides I'd have 2x functions for every method.

Is there any way to make it better?

Sorry for my English and mess, I've tried my best to explain my problem.
Hope you can understand what I mean.

Comment: A lot of this depends on the calling convention used by the program you are trying to hack into. I don't see anything wrong with pushing the 99 twice because the second 99 is part of a new stack frame. If the target program understands the calling convention used by your compiler it should correctly access the argument.

Comment: Anyhow, if you absolutely have to manage the calling convention yourself, I would do it completely in assembly in `CHARACTER::SetLevel(int lv)`. No need to add an extra function.

Comment: My first example, push everything twice and it works. I just want to make it faster, since some hooks are in loops (and it's server's binary so i have like 1000 players or 100k items) I want to do it as fast as possible. Doing it in assembly... asm() adds 'push ebp, mov ebp', esp at the beggining at that's not good (btw i fixed code)

Comment: It's not asm() that adds that. It's already there at the beginning of your function regardless of asm(). These instructions are used to conveniently save the stack pointer so that the stack frame of the function can easily be accessed. Your program should still work with them. You can put back your asm() inside SetLevel.

Comment: OOOh, right, i'm dumb. But is there any way to make it JUST JMP address ? (G++ freebsd)

Comment: Actually, I would have used your first version with the double push. 1 extra push on the stack is really not a big deal.

Comment: But sometimes there are even 10 arguments, and those functions are called very very often. Of course it's runing on powerfull dedicated server, but still. Less lag is always better (it's MMORPG game)

Comment: When you get the double push, is this for a debug build or a release build? Usually in release builds the compiler should be able to inline simple functions such as CHARACTER::SetLevel(int lv) and thus not generate any stack frame for it which would avoid the first push.

Comment: I always compile in debug. And i'd like to not change that. If there is any way to do inlines

Comment: In debug as in no optimizations?

Comment: g++ --save-temps -Wall -fPIC -Wl,-E -masm=intel -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -shared -o preload_new.so -g main.cpp CHARACTER.cpp ITEM.cpp DESC.cpp

Comment: This has no optimization enabled (the -O switch is missing). If you insist on not enabling optimization, I think 10 stack pushes should be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 0):

Move the definition of `CHARACTER::SetLevel()` into the header file and mark it for inlining.